# How to understand the base address in Legacy PCI BARs?

Tags: pci, pci-bus

I've been scratching my head trying to understand the BAR addressing in Legacy PCI.

At tho moment I'm having trouble understanding how the size and starting location of a BAR is allocated. From what I understand the size is determined by the number of bits right of the rightmost '1'. But I do not really understand how to specify the starting address.

- Suppose I have a BAR initialised to address 0xA8003000 and another at 0xA8002000, what's the difference between them?
- Suppose I want to assign a BAR with 4KB of address space starting at 0, what would be the input value to the BAR?

[This is what I found in the PCI documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry72O.png)

Comment: 0 is barely valid address (only some exceptional systems have a 0 mapped that can be written into), but in any case PCI bus is **relocatable**, write 0 to the BAR and you get it. But be sure there is no other device with the same address in the BAR. What you found is decoding of the LSBs which are there to distinguish IO/MMIO and other things. On PCIe the bit 2 is used to describe 64-bit BAR. They are not used in real addresses as by specification the address has to be aligned for at least 4 (8) bytes.